# the way to write ascii code file and Check it

Tags: c#, file, ascii

I have to write an ASCII and have the schemah, each row should be 128 characters, I took string and string and attached so that each field received his position, the test was exactly 128 characters, but in edit.com it's not the right place, I asked how to make the file ascii code? And is there a way to write each string a certain position?
 I can not upload the schamah is not in English, also, it i do not speak English and sorry for the mistakes.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely don't write your file with ASCII encoding - try this:

```
string myRow =string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("A", 128));
string[] rows = new string[] { myRow, myRow };
File.WriteAllLines(@"test.txt", rows, Encoding.ASCII);
```

This produces a text file where each line is encoded in ASCII (one byte per character) and rows are separated by `\r\n` characters. The sample produces a file with a size of 260 bytes, 128 bytes for each row plus 2x the two characters for line seperation.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time code ascii What is the "A" in the first row, if possible a bit more explanation would be very grateful

Comment: @mnachem: That was just sample input - all the first line does is create a string of 128 A's as test input for writing the file