# How to change text file encoding pragmatically using C# in WinRT/Windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I need to change the encoding of some text file from **UTF-8** to **ASCII** pragmatically in my Windows store app project(c#). On WinRT/Win8.1, we can do this simply by manually open it with notepad and then choose "Save as" menu, but my question is how to do it in code(c#)?

**[EDIT]**

In WinRT, we can use **FileIO.WriteLinesAsync()** or **FileIO.WriteTextAsync()** to save a string to text file, but we can only specify **UnicodeEncoding** as the encoding. So, the SDK is quite different compare to full fledged .NET SDK.

**[EDIT]**
I know ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, but I really need to make sure the file encoding is ASCII, because I want to upload the file to a web site and it only accept ASCII encoding txt files(UTF-8/Unicode encoding would cause it complain file format error!);

**[EDIT]**

Problem solved:

```
public async void SaveStringToAnsiFile()
{
    StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, Encoding.GetEncoding("gb2312").GetBytes("abcd→1234"));
}
```

Comment: I need to save a string to ASCII file, but using FileIO.WriteTextAsync() can't save it to file with ASCII encoding.Please see my last post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254608/how-to-save-string-to-text-file-with-ascii-encoding-in-windows-store-apps-winrt).

Comment: This is a duplicate, please see: [the way to write ascii code file and Check it [closed]][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725703/the-way-to-write-ascii-code-file-and-check-it

Comment: It's not duplicate.In WinRT, we can't pass Encoding.ASCII as the parameter to File.WriteAllLines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ASCII isn't directly supported, you'll need to convert the text to a byte array and use something like `WriteBytesAsync` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.writebytesasync)). Here's a simple technique. Of course, non-ascii characters won't work (but that's not what you need anyway).

```
string str = "these are characters";
byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length];

for (var i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(str[i]);
}

// create the file here ... then ...
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, bytes);
```

Comment: Greate idea! But unfortunately my text to be saved does contain some Non-ASCII char like "→". So is there any work-around?(I can manual save these non-ASCII text to ASCII file which is accepted by the web site. It's so curious!)thx!

Comment: How can you save an ASCII file that isn't ASCII? It's not ASCII then. It seems more like UTF-8 would be necessary.

Comment: but we can save it to ASCII file manually using notepad. When we choose the "save as" menu, we can then choose ASCII encoding. That's very curious.

Comment: Notepad has an option for ANSI. Not ASCII. And further, if you actually save a file with ANSI, it will warn that the file contains characters that will be lost (as they cannot be encoded in a simple ANSI file) and instead must be saved in a Unicode format.  Try copying the → into a new Notepad file, `Save As`, `ANSI`.

Comment: You're right, the optional encoding is ANSI. I have tried saving the → to ANSI, and got not warning. (Windows 8.1 pro)

Comment: I'm also running 8.1. Open the file again -- Unless your code page has that character in it (I'm using en-US/1252), it cannot preserve that character. It's not ASCII.

Comment: That's it, the active code page of my system is 936. Gread job, thx!Still wonder how to change UTF-8 file to ANSI progmatically like notepad.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45816/discussion-between-wiredprairie-and-simonfisher)